# procedure call not working from java call

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure which updates a table row in DB and returns a specific string(e.g 'done') after the update it returns a different response if the value is not updated(e.g 'fail').

When calling from MySQL tool it's updating the table and returning the value in response

```
call LoginCheck('9111111114','AGGR001002','11d3ad9315b7be5dd53b31a273b3b3aba5defe700808305aa16a3062b76658a791','DIST001007');
```

However when I am calling the same procedure from Java code it's returning the proper response i.e 'done', but when I am checking the table it seems that it has not updated the respective table row.

```
factory = DBUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
String status = "7000";
List objectList = null;    
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("call LoginCheck(:userid,:AggId,:Password,:id)");   
    query.setString("userid", userid);
    query.setString("AggId", AggId);
    query.setString("Password", Password);
    query.setString("id", id);

    objectList = query.list();
```

I have already tried `query.setParameter` and `query.ExecuteUpdate()`

Please let me know if anything else is required from my side.

Comment: Have you checked the autocommit settings of the MySQL datasorce in your program configuration? The fact that the procedure returns the correct value, but the database is not updated, suggests that the transaction is not committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have  begin your  transaction  but not committed it . so try commit it .

Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

**transaction.commit()**

Comment: Thank you,@EvgenyTanhilevich and @Tejal  :D